# Getting error while installing hardhat-toolbox

Tags: javascript, json, npm, blockchain

i have installed the following dependencies from the command

```
npm install --save-dev hardhat @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers
```

but after this when i try to install hardhat-toolbox i get the error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: smart_contract@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: ethers@5.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ethers
npm ERR!   dev ethers@"^5.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer ethers@"^6.1.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@3.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers
npm ERR!   peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@"^3.0.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@5.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
npm ERR!     dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@"^3.0.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@2.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers
npm ERR!     peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@"^2.0.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@5.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
npm ERR!       dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

here is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "smart_contract",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
        "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.6",
        "chai": "^5.1.0",
        "ethereum-waffle": "^4.0.10",
        "ethers": "^5.7.2",
        "hardhat": "^2.22.1"
    }
}
```

stuck on this since long plz help

Comment: Why do you have an explicit dependency on `ethers`? What happens if you remove the version constraint from that?

Comment: same error with chai dependency now
did
"devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.6",
    "chai": "^5.1.0",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^4.0.10",
    "ethers":"",
    "hardhat": "^2.22.1"
  }

Comment: OK well why do you have *that* dependency? The error you're getting comes from conflicts between your own package and some of the other packages you want to use. You have to resolve those conflicts. How exactly you do that depends on the reasons you're using the versions you're using.